# Hide loading label of WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, loading

I am having a slight problem recently with the Android's WebView.

While loading scripts (from assets), a small label at the bottom appears says loading which script. Like this :

[image]

I have seen some apps using WebView without this loading. What is a way to remove it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's specific to MathJax. You should check their documentation to see if you can disable it.

Comment: No i am pretty sure it is not for mathJax since on PC Chrome it doesn't appear, moreover , when loading other scripts it appears.

Comment: Hmm, could be. I just know that about the only time I ever see a script caption like that is when MathJax is loading.

Comment: I'm very sorry you were right. It was too low and small on the PC Chrome i didn't notice it.

Comment: Ah, cool. I was just starting to poke around to see what else that could be. Anyhoo, I know like zero JavaScript, but maybe this might be of use to you: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Hide-render-statusbar.